# Adding footer to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

So, I made a UITableView, with custom cell's (.xib files), that works well. The problem is that I now want to add a footer, that needs to have a UIImageView and a UILabel.

This is what I'm currently doing: *(of course I'm executing this function inside `viewDidLoad()` )*

```swift
private func setupTableViewFooter() {
        /// Insight Logo
        let myAppLogo = UIImageView()
        myAppLogo.backgroundColor = .clear
        myAppLogo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 110.0).isActive = true
        myAppLogo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0).isActive = true
        myAppLogo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        myAppLogo.image = UIImage(named: "myAppLogo")
        
        /// Description Label
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = .clear
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.size.width - 60).isActive = true
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0).isActive = true
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.textColor = K.Colors.black
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 13)
        label.text = "Hello world!"
        
        /// Stack View
        let footer = UIStackView()
        footer.axis = .vertical
        footer.distribution = .fill
        footer.alignment = .leading
        footer.spacing = 00.0
        footer.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        footer.addArrangedSubview(myAppLogo)
        footer.addArrangedSubview(label)
        footer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            footer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 30),
            footer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -30),
            footer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -60),
            footer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90)
        ])
        
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer
    }
```

I get this error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x282fa0640 "UIStackView:0x108022090.left"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x282f56400 "UIView:0x108020ec0.left"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I'm not used to set constraints programmatically, so it's getting really hard for me to solve this. Please help!

Comment: As the exception says; You can't add constraints between the view and the stack view because the stack view isn't a sub view of `view`

Comment: You just need the height constraint "When assigning a view to this property, set the height of your view to a nonzero value. The table view respects only the height of your view's frame rectangle; it adjusts the width of your footer view automatically to match the table view's width"

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks again for answering. So the solution would be to just set the height constraint for the views inside the stack view? What should I change? Sorry, but I just can't seem to fully understand. @Paulw11

Comment: Just set a height constraint on the stack view to start with. You will probably want the size constraints on the image too. The stack view lays out content, that is its purpose so you don't need to set other constraints.

Comment: The answer from @hoseinalialborzi stopped my app from crashing, it loaded the "footer", but as a header :( Any idea about what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add the fotter to tableView then add the Constraints

100% ok tested

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ footer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 30), footer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -30), footer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -60), footer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90) ])
```

Comment: Hey it solved the error, thank you! But it placed the footer as a header.. strange

Comment: I just noticed that not only it's been placed as a header, but that it's also been placed in front of my first 2 cells (can't see them).

Comment: I finally solved this strange behavior, by creating a method which returned not a `UIStackView`, but instead a `UIView` that contains the image and the label with already applied constraints (both with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`) over that `UIView`. After that I returned the view as the footer using `UITableViewDelegate` method: `viewForFooterInSection`, and set its height with `heightForFooterInSection`. Pd: I'm going to mark your answer as the solution since it solved the error I asked about, and it led me to set the footer the way I wanted.